# Storing an auto-generated random number using Java Netbeans and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, random, storage, auto-generate

Do you guys know how to store an auto-generated random number into mysql database? I really have no idea and I have been searching the internet for hours already. Can you guys help me? I am using Java Netbeans and MySQL workbench.

Comment: Please be more specific about having no idea. You have no idea how to generate numbers? You have no idea how to store number in database? You have no idea how to connect to database?

Comment: Sorry. What I mean is that I don't know how can I store the generated numbers on my database.

Comment: Do you know, what jdbc is and how to use it to connect to a database?  Do you use a framework already, or you're writing a standalone application from scratch? If so, are you using any libraries?